# XML validation against XSD: schemaLocation value must have even number of URI's

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a **blog.xml** and a **Blog.xsd** to validate the XML file. I am using http://www.xmlvalidation.com/?L=0 to validate both files but I'm getting an error.

Can you kindly tell me whats wrong?

**Error:**
[image]

**blog.xml:**

http://pastebin.com/He3xCxxC (sorry had to post it to pastebin (Due to SO's word limit)

**Blog.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="blog">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="post" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ptitle"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="psubtitle"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="image"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="author"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="date"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="par"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="source"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="comments"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="id" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Your xml is not available any more in pastebin. Provide at least the representative xml fragment, so that your post could be useful for others.

Comment: Don't paste the screenshot of the parsing output. This won't be indexed in the search machine (and even in that case, we cannot search that test in the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set the `targetNamespace` (ie "http://www.w3schools.com") of the schema.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

And `schemalocation` must specify the namespace and the schema. This is why you must have an even number of elements in `schemaLocation`.

```
<a:blog xmlns:a="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com ./Blog.xsd">
```

Comment: Where do I put that? And how ?

Comment: I still get errors:  7: 129 SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = '/Blog.xsd' must have even number of URI's.
 7: 129 cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'a:blog'.

Errors in file xml-schema:
 1: 165 TargetNamespace.2: Expecting no namespace, but the schema document has a target namespace of 'http://www.w3schools.com'.

Comment: @Brian What you're working on is probably just a learning exercise, but as a general rule, you shouldn't be using someone else's namespace for your own XML format.